# How do I go back to previous Git Commit?

Tags: git

How do I go back to previous commit?

I would like my files to look exactly like all my files did when I committed the below commit.

```
$ git log
commit 81cf7fa47adc0923aeabe323778e2783f2e832f5
Date:   Thu Apr 2 21:32:27 2015 +1000
```

I looked around an so many people have different answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always checkout to specific commit in git by following command

```
git checkout commit_hash
```

So in you case it will be

```
git checkout 81cf7fa47adc0923aeabe323778e2783f2e832f5
```

Or HEAD@{1} is the pointer to the one commit back so following will do the same

```
git checkout HEAD@{1}
```

Comment: Yes my files still look the same though... Is there something else to do?

Comment: maybe it's in previous commit... try to pickup the commit before it (find old commit using `git log`)

Comment: you can also check the difference btw the commits using command `git diff commit-hash`

Answer (score 0):

To See Last Commit :

Way 1 : In Terminal type User$ **gitk**

Way 2 : In Terminal type User$ **Git Gui** -> Click **'Ammend Last change'** radio button On Right Bottom Corner